# Where is a memory address' name/label stored?

Tags: memory, memory-management, organization

It'd be better if i explain this with an analogy. Here it goes...

1.There's a house at 52, Park Avenue -- (The memory address)

2.I reside in it -- (Data)

3.If you ask me where i live, I'd say '52, Park Avenue' (Im referring to the memory location)

But a house has its 'Number and Street name' in its front lawn as a 'Sign/Board' even if i move out or reside in it... either way!
Now where is this 'Sign/Board' stored for a memory location?

Simply put - How do we know that a particular memory address is 'x0y34vf' for example?

Comment: I don't think you do.  If I give you an arbitrary piece of data in the computer's memory without referring to it by its address, you have no idea where it is unless you go searching for it..

Comment: Every memory location has a name/label right? Another way to put it is like in a magnetic drive (for exmp), how does the r/w head know where to look for if the memory address is specified as some 'x034'?

Comment: Well put it this way.  If you had one big long street, and each house was numbered sequentially starting at 1, and there was one house every 100 yards.  You could pretty quickly figure out how far you need to drive to find the house with the address "25".

Answer (score 0):

Memory is mapped into a table which contains two sets, virtual address like the hex one and the actual sector and page that it should go if that address is asked for.

Now a question you might ask is, why is it that every time i access the same hex address, i get different values though they are garbage.

The answer is that when you compile and run your program, the program is loaded to RAM(Random Access Memory) and swapped out when you finish it running. So the first time your program might get a space at say literally at block 90 as the ram was free. But on second run time, the program might be loaded at another block say 720. This answers half only.

Similarly, the page mapping tables are updated for free space and space utilization and hence though the address remains same in the source code, while executing you get different values for that address.